# How to install Python 3.7 or 3.8 into OpenJDK docker container without building from source?

Tags: python, docker, debian, apache-flink, pyflink

I want to use the official Flink image on Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/flink) for use with PyFlink (specifically the 1.14.4 version). That image is based on the `openjdk:11-jre` base image which is Debian 11.3.

Debian 11 does not seem to have Python 3.8 in its package repository (only 3.9). Is there a way of installing Python 3.7 or 3.8 into the OpenJDK image without building it from source? I can't use 3.9 as Flink does not support this yet.